# Copy folder using Copy-Item - different behaviour

Tags: powershell

I want copy whole folder to another folder using `Copy-Item`.

My source folder `c:\base` contains some files:

```
├───base    
│       file1.txt
│       file2.txt
```

I use the following command:

`Copy-Item c:\base c:\target -recurse`

if the target folder (`c:\target`) exists, the command copies source folder exactly as I want:

```
├───target
│   └───base    
│           file1.txt
│           file2.txt
```

If the target folder doesn't exist, the command creates target folder (exactly as I want), **but now it copies only the content of the source folder** (without the `base` folder):

```
├───target    
│       file1.txt
│       file2.txt
```

- Why does it happen?
- How can I use this copy command (additional keys?) without create the target folder before?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a known bug ( feature some would say):

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/msg/3327f2d1544e7fb6?as_umsgid=6CAEDDC7-0F1A-4B21-8FB0-E6102A16EB51@microsoft.com

> This behaviour IMO, is an artifiact of
>   the provider and object   pipeline
>   model that powershell uses. You have
>   to get used to the idea   that the
>   navigational context is a bit weird
>   compared to other shells;   it's
>   explicit as opposed to implicit, since
>   the filesystem is one of   many
>   contexts that can be used. This brings
>   with it some weird   behaviours since
>   the targets of any given path are
>   handled with a   combination of
>   powershell's generic grammar and the
>   command itself, as   opposed to being
>   entirely handled by the command in
>   shells like   command.com/cmd.exe.

Comment: You should provide the actual solution that was posted into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this one is a really nasty.

If you want to have a consistent copy experience, use this pattern:

```
$copyFrom = 'C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy'
$destinationPath = 'D:\Bar\Foo\'

$newItemParams = @{
    Path        = $destinationPath
    ItemType    = 'Directory'
    Force       = $True
}

$copyParams = @{
    Path        = $copyFrom
    Destination = $destinationPath
    Recurse     = $True
    Confirm     = $false
    Force       = $True
}
New-Item @newItemParams
Copy-Item @copyParams
```

#### Result

The directory `D:\Bar\Foo\` will have `TargetDirectoryToCopy` directory nested inside.

So if there is a file `C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy\FooBar.txt`, its copy will be created as `D:\Bar\Foo\TargetDirectoryToCopy\FooBar.txt` along with any another file in `C:\Foo\Bar\TargetDirectoryToCopy`