# powershell Get-Item how to denote destination is a folder to be created?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy all files from the source directory to a destination directory which should be created if not existed by using Copy-Item.

First try:
Copy-Item 'C:\sourcePath\reports' 'C:\destPath\reports' -Force -Recurse

All is well.  However, if I run the command again, powershell instead of copying the content in C:\sourcePath\reports, creates an additional reports subfolder under C:\destPath\reports.  I end up with C:\destPath\reports\reports.

Other tries:

Copy-Item 'C:\sourcePath\reports*' 'C:\destPath\reports' -Force -Recurse
This one doesn't create the destination path C:\destPath\reports

Copy-Item 'C:\sourcePath\reports**' 'C:\destPath\reports' -Force -Recurse
This one copies the content into a reports file, not folder.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working?  This

Comment: There seems to be a bug with the way copy-item handles directory copies, see [this link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/20b9d259-90d9-4e51-a125-c0f3dafb498c/). You could do something more complicated and check the existence of the folder beforehand. else, and I hate to say this, but robocopy may be the way to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy folder using Copy-Item - different behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926346/copy-folder-using-copy-item-different-behaviour)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `robocopy`. It was designed for this kind of task.

```
robocopy C:\sourcePath\reports C:\destPath\reports /s
```