# Copy-Item behaves differently depending on whether target folder exists

Tags: powershell

Simple task, I'm trying to copy the following file/folder structure to a new location (source2):

```
c:\
----source
--------source
```

using the following command:

```
Copy-Item C:\source C:\source2 -Recurse -Force
```

This results in the desired output on first run:

```
c:\
----source2
--------source
```

However on second run it creates an additional "source" folder under "source" i.e.:

```
c:\
----source2
--------source
------------source
```

Why is this and what is the correct way to make this script repeatable?

Comment: See my original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278956/4553982) in a duplicated question.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [quirk in the Copy-Item behaviour](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/20b9d259-90d9-4e51-a125-c0f3dafb498c/copyitem-not-overwriting-exising-files-but-creating-additional-subfolder?forum=winserverpowershell).

> Copy-Item is confusing because, when copying a folder, if the
>   destination doesn't exist it assumes you're trying to copy/rename the
>   source to be the destination, whereas if the destination exists it
>   assumes you're trying to copy underneath it.
>
> This is really annoying behavior and you can vote to change it by
>   up-voting the issue here.

Unfortunately the issue link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Copy-Item C:\source\* C:\source2 -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: This produces strange behavour if c:\source2 doesn't exist yet, creates an empty file (not folder) in c:\ called 'source2' ?