# Copy-Item is copying unexpected folder

Tags: powershell, copy, directory-structure

I'm struggling to understand how PowerShell handles recursion and `Copy-Item` command.

```
$date=Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$oldfolder="c:\certs\old\$date"
New-PSDrive -Name "B" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\(server)\adconfig"
$lastwrite = (get-item b:\lcerts\domain\wc\cert.pfx).LastWriteTime
$timespan = new-timespan -days 1 -hours 1

Write-Host "testing variables..."
Write-Host " date = $date" `n "folder path to create = $oldfolder" `n 
"timespan = $timespan"

if (((get-date) - $lastwrite) -gt $timespan) {
#older
Write-Host "nothing to update."
}
else {
#newer
Write-Host "newer certs available, moving certs to $oldfolder"
copy-item -path "c:\certs\wc" -recurse -destination $oldfolder 
copy-item b:\lcerts\domain\wc\ c:\certs\ -recurse -force
}
```

Existing files exist at `c:\certs\wc\cert.pfx`
I have the "test" comparing the time between the `cert.pfx` in the `b:\lcerts\domain\wc\` folder and the current time . If the cert has been modified in the past 1 day and 1 hour, then the script should continue:

Copy `cert.pfx` from `c:\certs\wc\ to c:\certs\old\$date\cert.pfx`

Copy `cert.pfx` from `b:\lcerts\domain\wc to c:\certs\wc\cert.pfx`

I obviously don't understand PowerShell nomenclature for this because the first time I run this script, it works fine. The second time it creates another folder inside `c:\certs\wc\$date\wc\cert.pfx`.

How do I get it to fail with `"c:\certs\wc\$date\cert.pfx` already exists?"

I don't want to restrict this to just the `cert.pfx` file by specifying the actual file name, I want all files in the folder as eventually there will be more than one file.

Comment: you say that you are comparing the `c:\certs` date with the remote file ... but this >> `if (((get-date) - $lastwrite) -gt $timespan) {` << is doing nothing of the sort. it's comparing `now` with the LastWriteTime of the _remote_ file. ///// also, are you copying a file in one directory, a set of files in one directory, or files in a directory structure?

Comment: You're correct, it is comparing the "now" time. I mis-typed that. I don't understand your second question. I want to copy all the files from b:\lcerts\domain\wc to c:\certs\wc, and from c:\certs\wc to c:\certs\old\$date\wc

Comment: the 2nd question is "why are you using `-Recurse`? is there a directory structure involved or just a set of files in ONE directory that will be copied to ONE other directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy folder using Copy-Item - different behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926346/copy-folder-using-copy-item-different-behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `Copy-Item` when a directory is specified in the `-Path` parameter depends on whether the directory specified in the `-Destination` parameter exists.

```
Copy-Item -Path "c:\certs\wc" -Recurse -Destination "c:\certs\old\$date"
```

If the `c:\certs\old\$date` directory does not exist, then the `wc` directory is copied and named `c:\certs\old\$date`.

If the `c:\certs\old\$date` directory exists, the `wc` directory is copied under the `c:\certs\old\$date` directory. Therefore, it becomes `c:\certs\old\$date\wc`.

So you are sure to check in advance if the directory exists.

```
if(Test-Path $oldfolder) { throw "'$oldfolder' is already exists." }
Copy-Item -Path "c:\certs\wc" -Destination $oldfolder -Recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing if the destination folder exists. Seeing you are creating its name using a current date, it is more than likely this folder does not yet exist, so you need to create it first.

Also, There should be no need to use the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet, because `Copy-Item` is perfectly able to use UNC paths.

Something like this perhaps:

```
$server      = '<NAME OF THE SERVER>'
$serverPath  = "\\$server\adconfig\lcerts\domain\wc"
$testFile    = Join-Path -Path $serverPath -ChildPath 'cert.pfx'
$localPath   = 'c:\certs\wc'
$date        = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$timespan    = New-TimeSpan -Hours 1 -Minutes 1
$oldfolder   = "c:\certs\old\$date"

# check if this output path exists. If not, create it
if (!(Test-Path -Path $oldfolder -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Host "Creating folder '$oldfolder'"
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $oldfolder | Out-Null
}

Write-Host "testing variables..."
Write-Host "date = $date`r`nfolder path to create = $oldfolder`r`ntimespan = $timespan"

# test the LastWriteTime property from the cert.pfx file on the server
$lastwrite = (Get-Item $testFile).LastWriteTime
if (((Get-Date) - $lastwrite) -gt $timespan) {
    #older
    Write-Host "Nothing to update."
}
else {
    #newer
    Write-Host "Newer cert(s) available; copying all from '$localPath' to '$oldfolder'"
    Copy-Item -Path $localPath -Filter '*.pfx' -Destination $oldfolder
    Copy-Item -Path $serverPath -Filter '*.pfx' -Destination $localPath -Force
}
```

Comment: Testing for the folder I guess is what I needed. It's not how I originally intended but for what I'm doing it'll work. I did move the output path test into the "else" of the lower test so it wouldn't be created empty folders every day when the scheduled job runs.