# [Powershell]: 2nd Execution of Copy-Item creates subfolder (5.1.17763.1007)

Tags: powershell, copy-item

After searching for a wile I need to post my question here:
I want to do a simple task:

```
copy-item -path "C:\Folder Copied" -destination "C:\Folder Copied_New" -recurse
```

Assuming the dir "Folder Copied_New" doenst exist in "C:", PS will create a folder, and copy the folder (and its content) "C:\Folder Copied" to "Folder Copied_New"

HOWEVER, if you execute the command a second time, the following happens:

Powershell created: "C:\Folder Copied_New\Folder Copied" (content "Test.txt" was also copied to this newly created folder...

The 3rd time you execute the command, it ll say that the folder already exists...

So my question:
After I run the command a 2nd time, PS should throw an error, that "Folder Copied_New". How do I do that?

I tried copying and renaming the new folder, using and NOT using "" in the paths, but nothing worked. I do think of using -Testpath, but I thought I ask the community for a simplier (BestPractice) approache.

Thanks in advance for reading and advising!

[Well explained in another question but same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448878/14125382)

Comment: For me it shows your expected behavior. What Powershell Version do you have?

Comment: Just tested and I don't observe that behavior. There is something else missing in your question. Can you show us the minimal actual code that reproduces the issue on your device?

Comment: @T-Me 5.1.17763.100

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers edit the question so you can test it with just creating the folder "C:\Folder Copied", I just have a Test.txt in the folder for testing.

Comment: @Adis1102 - It should be up to you to provide a testscript, I'm not the one having issues. Can you try the testscript I've posted as an answer?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Sorry I am very new to powerscript and programming in generel. First of all, thanks for the testscript. I ve just learned something new.
It works as expected. However, the difference is that you have created already the destination, while in my code the destination folder is being created as PS executes the copy. Try your testscript with just line 10 being modified by me:

`New-Item $source <#, $destination#> -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null # Create folders`

Comment: @Adis - Now that *is* interesting. I have honestly no idea yet what to make of it.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The only solution what comes to my mind is to create the folders first and then to copy, but thought there is a shorter solution for it...still your testscript does indicate the answer, creating folders first.

Comment: @Adis1102 - I can't find it in the help but the `-Force` parameter of `Copy-Item` preserves the directory structure.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks for looking up, but still it doesnt work with `-Force`, it still creates a new folder within the newly created folder...

Comment: @Adis1102 - sorry, I'm out of options and this question will no longer attract many users. Perhaps better to post a new question, including a testscript that demonstrates the behavior (a further slimmed down version of what I've posted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is the default:

Let's say you want to copy and rename an item, so you are doing this:

```
Copy-Item -path source.txt -Destination destination.txt
```

You expect a file named `destination.txt` with the content of `source.txt`.

If you want to copy a file but without renaming it you do this:

```
Copy-Item -path source.txt -Destination C:\test
```

You expect the file `source.txt` to apear in `C:\test`. If `C:\test` didn't exist it will be created.

Now let's try to copy a folder while the destination does not exist.

```
Copy-Item -path C:\test -Destination D:\toast
```

The destination didn't exist so you created it by copying the source folder to the destination. The content of the destination will be the same as the source. The folder `D:\toast` is the same as `C:\test` but it got renamed in the process.
However if you provide a destination path where the source object (folder) is going to be located, it will be located in there.

```
 Copy-Item -path C:\test -Destination D:\toast
```

`D:\toast` did exist from our previouse action so a copy of `C:\test` will be created in there: `D:\toast\test`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very explanation. For me that behaviour seems fine: My thought was: What if the executer of this script runs it and then runs it againg because he forgot that he run it already? The 2nd execution will trigger a copy into an undesired subfolder. As I am a very beginner to programming in general, I though you might know a simple way I am not aware of.

Comment: the cmdlet `Copy-Item` has no parameter that would change that. The only opion would be to create the parent folder first to be sure to have a consistant behavior...

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but to long to write in comments.
Can you run following script and show us the output?

```
$root = "$($env:TEMP)\test"
$source = "$($root)\Logfiles"
$destination = "$($root)\Drawings\Logs"

# Verify folders don't exist yet
if (Test-Path $source) {Throw}
if (Test-Path $destination) {Throw}

# Set up
New-Item $source, $destination -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null # Create folders
New-Item "$($source)\testfile" -ItemType File -Force | Out-Null # Create a testfile

# Show files/folders before copy
Write-Output "Before copy"
Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | select fullname

# Copy first time
Copy-Item -path $source -destination $destination -Recurse -ErrorAction Continue
Write-Output "After first time copy"
Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | select fullname

# Copy second time
Copy-Item -path $source -destination $destination -Recurse -ErrorAction Continue
Write-Output "After second time copy"
Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | select fullname

# Copy third time
Copy-Item -path $source -destination $destination -Recurse -ErrorAction Continue
Write-Output "After third time copy"
Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | select fullname

# Clean up
Remove-Item $source, $destination -Force -Recurse | Out-Null
```

On my computer, I don't observe any abnormal behavior. The source folder get's copied to destination after the first time. The second run does not alter anything, neither does the third run.

[image]