# Powershell Copy-Item -recurse does not pick up new directory

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a binary PS module with PlatyPS help. I have a local poor-man's deploy script like this (PS 5.1):

```
$modulepath= "$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
$releasePath = ".\bin\release\net472"
# build project
dotnet build -c release
# build documentation
# requires PlatyPS module
New-ExternalHelp -Path .\docs -OutputPath $releasePath\en-US -Force 
ls $releasePath  # debug
# copy files
Get-ChildItem -Path $releasePath | Copy-Item -Destination $modulepath\PoshCommence -Recurse -Force 
ls $modulepath\PoshCommence  # debug
```

This ouputs the following surprising result:

```
Directory: X:\CustomModules\PoshCommence\bin\release\net472

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         17-2-2021     00:31                en-US
-a----         17-2-2021     00:24          36352 PoshCommence.dll

Directory: C:\Users\XXX\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshCommence

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         17-2-2021     00:31            871 about_PoshCommence.help.txt <- from en-US folder
-a----         17-2-2021     00:24          36352 PoshCommence.dll
-a----         17-2-2021     00:31         141080 PoshCommence.dll-Help.xml <- from en-US folder
```

None of the directories exist prior to running the script. I deleted the 'bin' project folder as well as the 'PoshCommence' module folder.

It seems either `Get-ChildItem` or `Copy-Item -Recurse` do not pick up the newly created 'en-US' directory, but the contents of it do get copied to the root level. If I run the script a second time (without deleting folders), it works as expected (except I still have docs stuff in the root of the module I don't want).

That has me stumped. I have tried `-Verbose` on everything, I put `Start-Sleep` after every line thinking operations may need time, but to no avail. Why isn't the 'en-US' folder picked up the first time?

Comment: How long is your start-sleep?  Once you write to the NTFS does not complete the write at that time.  It waits till the disk slows down to update the File Allocation Table.  This is done to speed up the OS.  There is a .refresh() method to force the update now.

Comment: @Aaron, that's interesting... Have any articles we can read about it?

Comment: Download procmon from sysinternals. Start it, run your script, stop it and search for the `en-US` folder being created (deleted?) and try drawing conclusions from there. *Note that if you run it without any filter applied, it will spew a ton of messages to wade through but it's doable.*

Comment: @Aaron I waited 60 seconds before copying;  the build of the module and generating te docs take like 2 seconds. In those 60 seconds I verified that everything in the 'bin' folder is as expected.

Comment: What I think happens is an issue with the `Get-ChildItem` and `Copy-Item`, unrelated to anything else in the script. If the target directory does not exist, it gets created, but no subfolders are created. Once the target directory does exist, subfolders are created. I suspect it is in the nitty gritty of `-Recurse`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this and chances of this being a bug in `Get-ChildItem/Copy-Item` are unlikely. If you try the procmon suggestion, I would add some `new-item file<n>-type file` in your script that would function as a debugstatement and is easily searchable in the procdump log. I'm guessing something is happening out of bound that you are not aware of. Procmon might bring that to light.

Comment: Not saying there's a bug, just that `Copy-Item` works differently from what I expected. [Old link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926346/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. My confusion stems from the fact that

```
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse
```

Works differently depending on whether the folder in $destination already exists or not.

So in the end all it took was

```
if (!(Test-Path $modulepath\PoshCommence)) { mkdir $modulepath\PoshCommence }
```

prior to the copying.

Comment: Good find (and good to know). ftr - I *would* call that a bug.

Comment: Well it seems the jury is still out on that, but it sure has been a frustrating journey for me.